# codeigniter edit details page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a page where user can go to edit the information he entered about himself. This is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>

</head>
<body dir="rtl">



<?php echo form_open('profile/edit'); ?>

<h5>الاسم الكامل</h5>
<input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo $fullname; ?>" />

<h5>الايميل</h5>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"  />


<h5>الجوال</h5>
<input type="text" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $mobile; ?>"  />

<h5>هاتف</h5>
<input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $telephone; ?>" />

<h5>العنوان</h5>
<input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo $address; ?>"  />

<h5>نبذة عني</h5>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="about" value="<?php echo $about; ?>"> </textarea>
<br><br>

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now when I submit, it shows me these errors:

[image]

I don't know what is happening. This only happens when I submit the form with edited data. Otherwise, it is loading correct details inside the fields in the first place.

Your help greatly appreciated: :)

Comment: while submitting those element does not have values. That is why you are getting this error.

Comment: where you are getting those variables from? Post the code also..

Comment: in your form you used $fullname , but there have no initialization for this variable...so fill vallue to this type of variables first

Comment: If variables have slashe " they may close your input value tag.. And this will cause all other html to fail.. so You must html escape them before loading them to your input values

Answer (score 0):

Try it .

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>

</head>
<body dir="rtl">



<?php echo form_open('profile/edit'); ?>

<h5>الاسم الكامل</h5>
<input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo (!empty($fullname)?$fullname:""); ?>" />

<h5>الايميل</h5>
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo (!empty($email)?$email:""); ?>"  />


<h5>الجوال</h5>
<input type="text" name="mobile" value="<?php echo(!empty($mobile)?$mobile:""); ?>"  />

<h5>هاتف</h5>
<input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo (!empty($telephone)?$telephone:""); ?>" />

<h5>العنوان</h5>
<input type="text" name="address" value="<?php echo (!empty($address)?$address:""); ?>"  />

<h5>نبذة عني</h5>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="about" value="<?php echo (!empty($about)?$about:""); ?>"> </textarea>
<br><br>

<div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This just reloaded the page when submitting to empty form.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you're not using the form helper class to generate the fields? Be sure the class is loaded via `$this->load->helper('form');` first and foremost. You can use form input helper via `echo form_input('username', 'johndoe');`. Also, your issue lies in your `value` fields. `$fullname` doesn't have a value so you'll need to compensate by doing something like:

```
// using HTML
<input type="text" name="fullname" value="<?php echo isset($fullname) ? $fullname : ''; ?>" />

// using form_input()
$data = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'name' => 'fullname',
    'value' => isset($fullname) ? $fullname : ''
);
echo form_input($data);
```

Hopefully this helps you!

Comment: hmmm it is giving me same error when using form_input instead of writing the fields myself. Thanks btw for helping with that. But How can I still solve the core problem?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure of setting the value to the view that have all the user info like email etc.
Better you check you repopulating info before rending to view with user info.

and in the view you have check the variable alreedy set or not by
`(!empty($fullname)? echo $fullname: '');`

hope this will help !!!